# Webclient DownloadFileCompleted to early?

Tags: c#, webclient

Below is the chunk that is downloading a uri. The file begins to download for a second then its calling it completed? The file was maybe 2% downloaded. What am i doing wrong here?

```
private void DownloadFiles()
{
    foreach (Patch patch in patches)
    {
        fileComplete = false;
        fileDownloadElapsed.Reset();
        fileDownloadElapsed.Start();

        CurrentPatch = patch;

        Uri uri = new Uri(patch.Uri);
        string uriPath = uri.OriginalString;
        currentFile = uriPath.Substring(uriPath.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        if (cbDebug.Checked)
            rtbDebug.Text += Environment.NewLine + String.Format("Downloading {0}...", currentFile.ToLower());

        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, currentFile);
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);

        while (!fileComplete)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1200);
        }
    }

    currentFile = string.Empty;
    updateComplete = true;
    progbarValue = 0;
    labelText = "Ready";
}
```

Comment: File may be compresses.  Without seeing the ProgressChanged Event can't tell if there could be other errors.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]